# Changing Font Size in Notes in UMLGraph

Tags: uml, graphviz, class-diagram, umlgraph

How it is possible to modify the default font size of UML notes in class diagram?

```
/**
 * @opt attributes  
 * @note How to modify font size of this text? 
 */
```

I tried with all documented *fontsize* options from the [documentation site](https://www.spinellis.gr/umlgraph/doc/indexw.html), but none of them modifies the note text font size.

```
/**
 * @hidden
....
 * @opt nodefontclasssize 22
 * @opt nodefontsize 14
 * @opt nodefonttagsize 14
 * @opt nodefontpackagesize 14
 * @opt edgefontsize 14 
.... 
 */
 class UMLOptions{}
```

I'm using UMLGraph-5.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add options to a comment on a class named `UMLNoteOptions`.  See the following example and result.

```
/**
 * @hidden
 * @opt nodefontsize 18
 */
class UMLNoteOptions{}

/**
 * @opt attributes
 * @note How to modify font size of this text?
 */
class Foo {}
```

[image: UMLGraph result]

Comment: [UMLNoteOptions](https://www.spinellis.gr/umlgraph/doc/indexw.html) did it! I'm using UMLGraph fora long time, but I did use only UMLOptions so far. Thanks a lot for the hint!